# How to Run Ad Hoc Database Queries in Open Jump?

Tags: postgis, openjump

Which plugin allows you to run ad hoc queries from postgis in Openjump? How do you install it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using postgresql with postgis extension I don't think you need a special plugin. The core application can do that for you.

1. Just go to Layer -> Run Database Query
2. Click the Connection Manager icon next to Connection.
3. Press Add, give it a name, choose driver POSTGIS and fill out the details how to reach your database.
4. Connect to it.
5. Enter a query (e.q. SELECT some_geometry_column FROM some_table_with_a_geometry_column;)
   and press OK

You should now see a layer showing your geospatial data.

Just install Open Jump through the package manager in Ubuntu. Or if you do not know how to do that see: http://geomaniaa.blogspot.com/2009/07/openjump-how-to-setup-on-linux-in-seven.html

Comment: The confusion was that the package manager only has version 1.0.4. Latest is 1.4.2, which has the run datastore query option. Instead of finding the run datastore query under the layer menu, I found it under the file menu.

Comment: I would vote this answer up and mark it as answer, but it tells me I need to be logged in...but I already am.